# Como puedo imprimir todos los datos registrados al final en c++

Tags: c++, bucle-for

quisiera imprimir el ultimo cout solo despues de haber ingresado todos los datos segun el numero de hermanos, pero en vez de eso se imprime uno por uno como en la imagen y yo quisera que despues de haber ingresado los datos segun la cantidad de hermanos se imprima esto:

Hermano[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLddF.png) Apellido: Varela, Mes: Junio, Dia: 12

Hermano[2] Apellido: Perez, Mes: Diciembre, Dia: 1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string nombre;
    int hermanos;
    string apellido;
    string mes;
    int dia;

    cout<<"Ingresa nombre: "<<endl;
    cin>>nombre;

    cout<<"Ingresa numero de Hermanos: "<<endl;
    cin>>hermanos;

    for (int i = 0; i < hermanos; i++) {
            cout<<"Apellido: "<<endl;
            cin >> apellido;

            cout<<"Mes de Nacimiento: "<<endl;
            cin>>mes;

            cout<<"Dia de Nacimiento: "<<endl;
            cin>>dia;
    cout <<"Hermano [" << i+1 << "] " << "Apellido: "<< apellido << ", Mes: " << mes << ", Dia: "<<dia <<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error de concepto en el programa. Primero debes agrupar todos los datos en un struct, por ejemplo:

```
struct Persona
{
    string nombre;
    string apellido;
    int hermanos;
    string mes;
    int dia;
    int anio;
}
```

Posteriormente declaras bien un array de Persona (si conoces el número de elementos que vas a utilizar), bien un vector.

```
Persona p[100];     // array de tipo Persona de 100 elementos
vector<Persona> p2  // vector de tipo Hermano
```

El acceso a cada uno de los datos es sencillo:

```
p[i].nombre = ....;
```

Igualmente cada uno de los elementos del struct puede ser a su vez un array o un vector.

Espero haberte sido de ayuda.

Comment: hola, el caso es que no se conocer el numero de elementos que se va a utilizar ya que el usuario lo debe ingresar

Comment: @mafer para añadir elementos al vector debes usar la función [`push_back`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) y para saber cuántos elementos hay en la colección usas la función [`size`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/). La clase `std::vector` está pensada precisamente para problemas como el tuyo, colecciones de tamaño variable

Comment: mafer... el orden debería ser... Preguntar número de hermanos (n) --> For de 0 a n-1 para pedir y guardar los datos de cada hermano en el array de los datos de hermanos --> Nuevo for de 0 a n-1 con los cout de cada hermano del array